# Facebook SDK gives too many errors after importing the samples

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I have followed the tutorial in facebook.com concerning how to integrate facebook into android applications. I have downloaded facebooksdk and imported the projects to a clean workspace on Eclipse. However after I have imported them , I got about 150 errors about "can not be resolved to a variable".

Among the samples there is also a FacebookSDK project that is imported. I assume that is the real library to be used for other samples ?. I have looked into the details. HEre is what I have found :

- FacebookSDK project doesnt have any library path problems. However, all other sample projects tries to find facebooksdk.jar in the bin folder of facebook project. And there is no such file. Also, I have not found a single thing about a facebooksdk.jar in google.

-The errors concerning FacebookSDK project are as follows :

R can not be resolved to a variable.

-The errors concerning Other sample projects are as follows :

Some resolving issues with imported functions and classes.

I appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: Right click on your project goto properties. goto java build path. Choose order export tab. Choose Android Private Libraries. Do the same for facebook library project. Also got android sdk manager and make sure you have android sdk build tools installed. this happens after updating sdk and adt to rev 22. May be the reason but i am not completely sure

Comment: Go to properties-> android and see if there are any red cross marks??

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps [mentioned here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

**Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0**, so simply make sure the project (or Eclipse) properties mandate v1.6 in the Java Compiler section.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Turns out unzipping was somehow broken, and now the problems is solved except some runtime errors.

Comment: I think you should answer your own question in this situation. Otherwise, you may keep getting down votes. (:

Comment: I dont even understand why I got downvoted. There are hundred million less thought questions in this site, and people are licking eachother in them. I love the internet hypocrisy.